# Python split a large file to multiple file

Tags: python, batch-file, find

I’m new to python and have a small bit of code that reads a list of files into a Windows batch file to execute. The trouble is, the code is (correctly) writing up 700 lines per batch file which would take an age to process on one PC. I’d like to break each batch file into, say 100 lines per batch script, and then run each batch file across 7 PC's, for example, but my lack of python knowledge is hampering me a little. I have;

```
def find_files(directory, pattern):
   #directory= (raw_input("Enter a directory to search for Userlists: ")
   directory=("c:\\test\\")
   os.chdir(directory)
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
       for basename in files:
           if fnmatch.fnmatch(basename, pattern):
               filename = os.path.join(root, basename)
               yield filename

for files in find_files('a-zA-Z0-9','*.btm'):
    #print files
    lines="call "+files +"\n"
    print lines
    with open ("c://Extract.bat","a+") as infile:
        infile.write(lines)
        infile.close
```

I've tried using (islice(f,n)) but it failed to write anything to 'extract.bat'. Any help, would, as always be really appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Is this your most recent code? It doesn't run.

Comment: why not do whatever the bat is supposed to do in python?

Comment: you don't use the first parameter of your method, which is weird given  its value.

Comment: @pypat, yeah, I plan eventually to do that, but it's probably a couple of weeks of teach myself python to do it. This batched way is something I can run today, hopefully.

Comment: @kevin it may be my rubbish formatting up on screen. It does work..kind of..honest :-)

Comment: add a counter and create a new file every N value. a simple i += 1 in each loop, and a int division in the name of the file is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quite simple way would be to put this in your loop :

```
i += 1 # don't forget to initialize it before the loop, though
with open ("c://Extract" + str(i/700) + ".bat","a+") as infile:
```

gives you a new file names Extract0.bat, Extract1.bat, ... every 700 line.

Comment: Excellent. Just what I was looking for. Very many thanks @njzk2